# django-rest-framework-bulk BulkUpdateView outuput customization

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a model called `Item` which has an `FSMField` (of [django-fsm](https://github.com/kmmbvnr/django-fsm)) called `status`.

```
class Item(models.Model):
    ...
    status = FSMField(choices=StatusChoices.choices, default=StatusChoices.INITIAL)

    @transition(field=status, source=StatusChoices.INITIAL, target=StatusChoices.ARRIVED)
    def mark_arrived(self):  # there are more such transitions
        pass
```

I have an API endpoint for bulk update where I take in transition names as input and call those those transition methods on the instance.

API input format:

```
[
    {
        'id': 23,
        'transition': 'mark_arrived',
    },
    {
        'id': 25,
        'transition': 'some_non_existent_transition_name',
    }
]
```

I came across a package called [djangorestframework-bulk](https://github.com/miki725/django-rest-framework-bulk) which seems suited for this task. Now this is my view:

```
from rest_framework_bulk import BulkUpdateAPIView
class ItemStatusChangeView(BulkUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Item.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ItemStatusSerializer
```

And This is my serializer class:

```
from rest_framework_bulk import BulkSerializerMixin, BulkListSerializer
class ItemStatusSerializer(BulkSerializerMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    transition = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=20, write_only=True)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        try:
            instance.__getattribute__(validated_data['transition'])()
        except AttributeError:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({'transition': 'No such Transition'})

        instance.save()
        return instance

class Meta:
    model = Item
    fields = ('id', 'transition')
    list_serializer_class = BulkListSerializer
```

Now as per above API input, I want API output format to look like:

```
[
    {
        'id': 23,
        'status_changed': True,
    },
    {
        'id': 25,
        'status_changed': False,
        'transition': 'No such Transition'
    }
]
```

But it looks like:

```
{
    'transition': 'No such Transition'
}
```

Is there an elegant way to do this?

(As far as that `status_changed` field in output is concerned, I know that I need to add a `read_only` field in `ItemStatusSerializer`, but I am confused regarding how to assign it some value during output.)

Comment: You should be doing your validation _before_ the `update` method is called. Try looking into the `validate` method on serializers.

Comment: Generally, you should not have things like `instance.__getattribute__(validated_data['transition'])` in you code. Instead you nned to create separate endpoint for each transition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I achieved my objective, (in a not so elegant way though).

As suggested by @Kevin Brown in comments, I changed my `ItemStatusSerializer` to look like this:

```
class ItemStatusSerializer(BulkSerializerMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    transition = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=50, write_only=True)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        return instance

    def validate(self, attrs):
        item = Item.objects.get(item_id=attrs['id'])

        try:
            item.__getattribute__(attrs['transition'])()
        except AttributeError:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({
                'id': item.id,
                'transition': 'No such Transition',
                'is_status_changed': False
            })

        item.save()
        return attrs

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('id', 'transition')
        list_serializer_class = BulkListSerializer
```

But still, I didn't fully attain my desired output:

```
[
    {},  # this one's transition ran successfully
    {
        'id': [25],
        'status_changed': [False],
        'transition': ['No such Transition']
    }
]
```

Why does the output for `item` for which `transition` ran successfuly, is empty? After digging deep through the code, I figured out:

If you have a look at `to_internal_value` method of `serializers.ListSerializer` (which is superclass of `BulkListSerializer`) class, you'll see this:

```
def to_internal_value(self, data):
    ...
    ...
    for item in data:
        try:
            validated = self.child.run_validation(item)
        except ValidationError as exc:
            errors.append(exc.detail)
        else:
            ret.append(validated)
            errors.append({})  # this was the culprit 

    if any(errors):
        raise ValidationError(errors)
    return ret
```

so I subclassed `BulkListSerializer` and overrode `to_internal_value` method, somewhat like this:

```
class ItemStatusChangeListSerializer(BulkListSerializer):

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        ...
        ...
        all_valid = True
        for item in data:
            try:
                validated = self.child.run_validation(item)
            except serializers.ValidationError as exc:
                all_valid = False
                exc.detail['id'] = exc.detail['id'][0]
                exc.detail['is_status_changed'] = exc.detail['is_status_changed'][0]  # this is just to avoid enclosing it's value in list
                errors.append(exc.detail)
            else:
                validated['is_status_changed'] = True
                del validated['transition']
                ret.append(validated)
                errors.append(validated)  # note this

        if not all_valid:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(errors)

        return ret
```

and then in `ItemStatusSerializer`'s meta class, I set the `list_serializer_class` variable to the above shown `ItemStatusChangeListSerializer`